# R. Multiply a different scalar to every element of a list and sum over the elements

Tags: r, list

Suppose a list object and a vector:

```
lst <- list(a = matrix(1:9, 3), b = matrix(2:10, 3))
vec <- c(2, 3)
```

And I want to get the result like

```
2 * a + 3 * b
```

I solve this by

```
matrix(apply(mapply("*", lst, vec), 1, sum), 3, 3)
```

But this looks a little cumbersome.

Is there an efficient way to get same result?

Comment: `eval(substitute(2*a + 3*b), lst)` works, though I know now if "efficient" is a word I would use to describe it ...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's any more efficient, but here's an idea that's a little cleaner.  You can use `Map()` for the multiplication and `Reduce()` to do the summing.

```
Reduce("+", Map("*", lst, vec))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    8   23   38
# [2,]   13   28   43
# [3,]   18   33   48
```

Also, in your code, you could replace the `apply()` call with `rowSums()`.  That would probably improve efficiency in what you've done.

Comment: Thank you very much! It looks much better.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is loop through the sequence of the list and then multiply

```
Reduce(`+`,lapply(seq_along(lst), function(i) lst[[i]]*vec[i]))
```

For the `list` and `vector` of two elements

```
lst[[1]]*vec[1] + lst[[2]] * vec[2]
```